# CKeditor тестирование Angular компоненты

Tags: ckeditor, angular, jasmine, karma

Пишу тесты для компоненты которая использует CKEditor.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [FormsModule],

  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
  declarations: [DocumentEditComponent],
  providers: [{provide: AppConfig, useValue: appConfig},
    {provide: DocumentsService, useValue: documentsService},
    {provide: NgbModal, useValue: modalService},
    {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRoute},
    {provide: BaThemeSpinner, useValue: loader},
    {provide: PopupResultService, useValue: popupResultService},
  ],
})

fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DocumentEditComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
```

При запуске теста вот такая ошибка. Есть идеи как имитирвоать его работу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что такое `CKEditor`? как вы его используете - как модуль `ckeditor` или ангуляровскую обертку `ng2-ckeditor`? где вы регистрируете модуль?

Comment: Помогли с решением https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51823311/ckeditor-and-jasmine-test-in-angular?noredirect=1#comment90600751_51823311